# How can I skip value in array using map or group elements in Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to print a list of persons that share same address and company name
My array:

```json
persons = [
 { address: "Wallstreet",
  company: "ABC",
  name: "John",
  telephoneNr: "12345"
 },
 { address: "Wallstreet",
  company: "ABC",
  name: "Rick",
  telephoneNr: "12857"
 },
 { address: "Wallstreet",
  company: "ABC",
  name: "Eva",
  telephoneNr: "38665"
 }
]
```

I am using map function, but I want to print address and company name only once, since they all share same address and same company. How can I skip printing addresses and company name for the second, third and n time in the loop?

```js
{persons.map((item, index) => {
  return (
    <p>
      {item.address}
    </p>
    <p>
      {item.company}
    </p>
    <p>
      {item.name}: {item.telephoneNr}
    </p>
)})}
```

My print looks like this:

```
Wallstreet
ABC
John:12345
Wallstreet
ABC
Rick:12857
Wallstreet
ABC
Eva: 38665
```

And I want my print to look like this:

```
Wallstreet
ABC
John:12345
Rick:12857
Eva: 38665
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update this code:

```
{persons.map((item, index) => {
              return (
                if (index === 0) {
                   <p>
                    {item.address}
                   </p>
                   <p>
                    {item.company}
                   </p>
                   <p>
                    {item.name}: {item.telephoneNr}
                   </p>
               } else { 
                   <p>
                    {item.name}: {item.telephoneNr}
                   </p>
               }
              )})}
```

Your output will be look like this:

```
 Wallstreet
 ABC
 John:12345
 Rick:12857
 Eva: 38665
```

Comment: It will work only if the address and company are in index 0

Answer (score 1):

You can use Map object [Map object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

```
const map = new Map()
map.set([address, company].toString(), [{name, telephoneNr}])
```

then you need to get the value and set it with the new item and if the key is the same it will map to the same key-value pair
and after that, you can iterate the map object and to print it